# Sails.js : How to insert values in mysql database

Tags: sails.js

I'm using Linux and, I'm trying to insert my Textbox values into mysql via sails.js. When I surfing the net, I didn't get any clear answer.

I have attached My Controller for create function

```
module.exports = {

create :function(req,res){

    if(req.method=="POST"&&req.param("User",null)!=null) 
    {

        var insert = "INSERT INTO User VALUES("+req.params.userId+",'"+req.params.loginName+"','"+req.params.userName+"','"+req.params.password+"','"+req.params.userMail+"')";

        User.query(insert,function(err,record){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("Error");
        }
        else
        {

            console.log(record);
            res.redirect('User/index');

        }

        }); 
    }   

},
```

this is my create.ejs

```
<form action="/user/create" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr><td>UserId:<td><input type="text" name="User[userId]"><br/>
        <tr><td>LoginName:<td><input type="text" name="User[loginName]"><br/>
        <tr><td>UserName:<td><input type="text" name="User[userName]"><br/>
        <tr><td>Password:<td><input type="text" name="User[password]"><br/>
        <tr><td>UserMail:<td><input type="text" name="User[userMail]"><br/>
        <tr><td><td><input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

connection.js  is:

```
module.exports.connections = {

mysql: {
    module    : 'sails-mysql',
    host      : 'localhost',
    port      : 3306,
    user      : 'root',
    password  : 'assyst',
    database  : 'User' 

},
```

};

How to do basic crud operations in sails.js with mysql.

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/irlnathan/mysqlEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expect if you create `User` API by `sails generate api user` it will automatically `UserController.js` at `api/controllers` and `User.js` at `api/models`.

Modify `User.js` at your `api/models/User.js` to

```
module.exports = {

  attributes  : {
    userId      : {type: 'string'},
    loginName   : {type: 'string'},
    userName    : {type: 'string'},
    password    : {type: 'string'},
    userMail    : {type: 'string'}
  }
};
```

By default, it expose [Blueprint API](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) and you can POST something to user model by:

```
<form action="/user" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr><td>UserId:<td><input type="text" name="userId"><br/>
        <tr><td>LoginName:<td><input type="text" name="loginName"><br/>
        <tr><td>UserName:<td><input type="text" name="userName"><br/>
        <tr><td>Password:<td><input type="text" name="password"><br/>
        <tr><td>UserMail:<td><input type="text" name="userMail"><br/>
        <tr><td><td><input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

That's the basic CRUD at Sails.

Comment: @Martin great to hear that. Don't forget to choose an answer to avoid misleading to other people who think this topic is still need an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my insert operation in sails.js with Mysql

```
Insert:function(req,res)
{
    if(req.method=="POST")
        {
            console.log("Post");
            var userId = req.param("userId");
            var userName = req.param("userName");
            var loginName =req.param("loginName");
            var password =req.param("password");
            var userMail =req.param("userMail");
            console.log(userName);

            var insert = "INSERT INTO User(UserId,LoginName,UserName,password,UserMail) VALUES("+userId+",'"+loginName+"','"+userName+"','"+password+"','"+userMail+"')";

            User.query(insert,function(err,record)
            {

                if(err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(record);
                    res.redirect('User/index');
                }
            });

        }
        else
        {
            res.render("create");
        }
},
```